# Elastic Search High Level Rest Client - passing an authentication cookie

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a wrapper rest service around elastic search APIs to build a search function from my UI. The users are authenticated from the UI, and the authentication vehicle is a cookie that both my UI/service and my Elastic Search setup/cluster can underastand. I intend passing through the same cookie from the UI to the backend ES cluster.

I create the rest client (RestHighLevelClient) as a singleton, so there is no elegant way to add the cookie into the header for each request. My access pattern is using the Spring data elastic search repositories and as such I have no granular control of what clients get used by the repository. What is a good way to solve this?

I'm using ES 7.8.0, Spring ES Data 3.2.12.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.12 had the possibility set set default headers to send to Elasticsearch when the client is  created by using the Spring Data Elasticsearch configuration classes, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.configuration.

But Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2 is long outdated and out of support, you should upgrade your whole setup to current versions.